# How to set Id to button created using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

//   how to set id to this created buttons?

```
for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
{       
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");// create       button using java script
    btn.className = "btnsize";

    var txt = document.createTextNode(num++);//creat text on button
    btn.appendChild(txt);//attached text on button
    document.getElementById("xyz").appendChild(btn);//atache button with text in div 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
 var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 btn.setAttribute("class","btnsize");
 btn.setAttribute("id","btnid"+i);
 var txt = document.createTextNode("button");
 btn.appendChild(txt);
 document.getElementById("xyz").appendChild(btn); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
btn.id = "btnid"+i
```

This will number them accordingly

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div id="xyz"></div>
```

js

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");// create       button using java script
    btn.className = "btnsize";
    btn.id = "btnid"+ i;
    var txt = document.createTextNode("aaasasa");//creat text on button
    btn.appendChild(txt);//attached text on button
    document.getElementById("xyz").appendChild(btn);//atache button with text in div 
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7ukL8pny/)

In you code `num` is not defined. you should add `i` in `btn.id = "btnid"+ i;` for unique ids.